# Is it possible to limit infinte recursion in an Oracle CTE?

Tags: oracle, cte, recursive

In a DBMS like Microsoft SQL, there is a default limit of 100 recursions, in a recursive CTE, which can be adjusted with:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    …
)
SELECT * FROM cte OPTION (MAXRECURSION …);
```

As far as I can tell, in PostgreSSQL, MariaDB and MySQL, you need to set a timeout.

Is there an option either for the number of recursions or a timeout for Oracle?

Comment: Check this stackoverflow.com/a/44765892/836215 . You can simulate functionality of pseudo column LEVEL. Or you can use setQueryTimeout() in JDBC. It is part of standart JDBC 4.2 and is implemented by Oracle's drivers.